# Changing page width and height using RegisterStartupScript method in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change page width and height using RegisterStartupScpript method:

I tried

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "default2", "<script height:350; width:200 type=text/javascript> </script>", true);
```

but it doesn't work. Can you help me? How can I do?

I find solution thanks for everone

```
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "window.open( 'Default2.aspx?adi=" + adi + "&soyadi=" + soyadi + "&ogrenci_no="+ogrenci_no+"&tel_no="+tel_no+"&sinifi="+sinifi+"', 'height=650,width=850,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no, scrollbars=yes' );", true);
```

Comment: Your question makes very little sense. What are you trying to achieve, because setting the size of a `<script>` doesn't make sense.  (Also, despite everything else, the `<script>` element you provide is badly formatted)

Comment: Sorry about my code I have no much more expierence in asp.net I want to change size of the page such that when it opens it opens in size which I want.

Comment: So when a user navigates to your webpage, you want the browser that is showing your webpage to automatically change size? (I would **strongly** recommend you don't do this.) Or are you dealing with a popup page that you want as a particular size?

Comment: when clicked bıtton it goes to another page and I want to resize this another pages.I want to decrease its width and height

Comment: In that case you are correct that you need to run a script on the client, but I would **strongly** recommend that you don't change the size of the browser, as it is one of the ways to guarantee your users will get annoyed

Comment: Is this "popup page" initiated by the `window.open` in javascript, or is it a new browser window initiated by `target="_blank"` type attribute on a link?

Answer (score 0):

Use window.open to open new window and set size of newly opened window, you might need to unblock popup.

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/ifiquy/2/edit)**, **press render button to popup**

```
window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
```